# Error : illegal initializer for Object

Tags: java

Espero me puedan ayudar.

Tengo algo de este estilo en un código de un archivo .java:

```
objeto = new Object[] { 
   { H1, H11, H12, H13}, 
   { H2, H21, H22, H23} 
}
```

Pero me marca el error:

```
illegal initializer for Object
```

Estoy inicializando mal mi objeto por lo que me marca el error? que formas tengo de inicializarlo? Debo tener esa estructura, gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Debería poner el código real para que se le pueda ayudar de una mejor manera.

Answer (score 2):

Saludos, Erik.

El error que te aparece, la verdad es por algo bastante simple, **y es que te faltó agregar una pareja de paréntesis cuadrados.**

Esto se debe a que al momento de inicializar cualquier tipo de Array, la cantidad de paréntesis indica las dimensiones que tendrá el mismo.

Esto quiere decir, que tú estás declarando `objeto` como una matriz de `Object` de **una** dimensión (es decir, `Object[]`), **pero,** al momento de llenar esa  matriz que creaste (lo cuál lo realizas con las llaves `{H1, H11....}`) estás indicándole que llene **dos dimensiones** (te das cuenta al agregar una coma, cada `,` indica una columna) cuando en realidad la matriz es **sólo** de una.

En resumen, tu problema se soluciona haciendo esto:

```
objeto = new Object[][] { 
   { H1, H11, H12, H13}, 
   { H2, H21, H22, H23} 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que intentas hacer, lo puedes hacer de estas dos formas:

```
String[][] arrays = { array1, array2, array3, array4, array5 };
```

O sino

```
String[][] arrays = new String[][] { array1, array2, array3, array4, array5 };
```

> La última sintaxis se puede usar en asignaciones que no sean la
>   de la declaración de la variable, mientras que la sintaxis más corta
>   solo funciona con las declaraciones.

Comment: Si hubieras brindado mas información de tu código, te hubiera podido dejar un ejemplo mas personalizado.

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo que pasa es que tengo 2 "grupos" que a su vez contienen esa lista de datos, es decir,  {array1,array2,array3},{array4,array5,array6} pero me marca error al declararlo

Comment: Cada "grupo" seria un Arrays de Arrays, no seria problema. Puedes tener " "x" dimensiones. Un matriz, como el ejemplo que te mostré, se le suele decir 2 dimensiones.

Answer (score 0):

Buenas EriK, la inicialización está mal realizada. La estructura no es la adecuada. Primero debes declarar que tu variable objeto va a ser un array tipo Object y luego la estructura te debe queda de la siguiente forma:

```
Object[] objeto = new Object[] { H1, H11, H12, H13, H2, H21, H22, H23};
```

Espero te sirva. Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, lo que pasa es que h1,h11,h12,h13 y h2,h21,h23 son grupos de datos diferentes, no sé si me explico jejeje.